# Fo-dicom: How to add "empty, if unknown" integer string type 2 attribute

Tags: dicom, fo-dicom

There is a tag which is of type 2 ("required, empty if unknown"), with value representation `Integer String` which I would like to leave empty. I have tried creating the attribute like so:

```cs
var attribute = new DicomIntegerString(DicomTag.SeriesNumber, string.Empty);
```

The storing of the file works. When I read the file again, the result of the following call returns `null`:

```cs
var result = dicomDataset.GetString(DicomTag.SeriesNumber); // <-- this is null
```

How can I set the element to be correctly "zero-length", or "empty, if unknown"?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you add the attribute - using `AddOrUpdate`? Have you checked that the tag is written with a DICOM tag viewer? Also: which version of fo-dicom yo are using?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I only use the `DicomDataset` constructors. I have checked now with `dcmdump`, and the tag is actually being written, with a "no value available." comment. Could it be that fo-dicoms methods for retrieving values, cannot differentiate between "no value found for that tag", and "tag found, but with empty value"? I'm using version `5.0.2`.

Comment: Yes, I think so, have to check. As far as I remember, an exception would have been raised if the tag was not found. Returning `null` or an empty string for an empty tag is a design decision, as there is no semantic difference between a non existing and an empty value (I remember a similar discussion in pydicom) and should be handled the same way by the client - though I agree that returning an empty string would be more convenient for string tags.

Comment: Confirmed that this is the behavior. As I wrote, in DICOM there is really no difference between a tag with no value or a tag with an empty value (at least for string tags), so it is up to the library to decide what to return in this case. As a user, you can just handle `null` values as empty strings for string tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, the code to set an empty string in the dataset is correct:

```cs
dataset.AddOrUpdate(new DicomIntegerString(DicomTag.SeriesNumber, string.Empty));
```

Note that you could also write a `null` value:

```cs
dataset.AddOrUpdate(new DicomIntegerString(DicomTag.SeriesNumber, (string)null));
```

Writing out the dataset will create an empty tag for `SeriesNumber` in exactly the same way in both cases, as both cases are equivalent in DICOM.

The code to read the tag back is also correct, and the fact that it returns `null` is due to this equivalence, which creates an ambiguity in the interpretation of an empty string tag in DICOM. As the number of values in a DICOM string tag is defined only by the string itself (and the number of backslashes it contains), there is no difference between a tag with no values (which usually is represented by a `null` value), and a tag with an empty string (which would be represented by a `""` value). For consistence with other tags it makes sense to return `null` for a tag with VM 0 - for non-string VRs there is no ambiguity here, as the length of a value is defined. For string values it could also make sense to return an empty string instead - both approaches have pros and cons, so in the end it is a design decision of the library creators.

In `fo-dicom`, it is probably best to handle both cases (e.g. using something like `string.IsNullOrEmpty`). If you read the value from a file dataset, you always get `null`, but if you are writing an empty string to a tag in a dataset (first version shown above) and read it back, you will get the same empty string back.

As an aside: in `pydicom` (the common Python DICOM library) there was a [discussion](https://github.com/pydicom/pydicom/issues/896) about this same design decision, and in the end a configuration entry was added that defines the behavior (e.g. return `None` or an empty string for such values).